# vb.net class libary - exception handling for ado.net queries

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

Can someone please advise - we want to log a detailed error message to a text file or sql server for any error occurred in .net library which we created.

```
Try
    'Here we are using the sql command object to fetch the required data
    Catch ex As Exception
    'Here we want to capture detailed error information in a text file or 
    'sql server
Finally
    If Not _SQLCommand Is Nothing Then
        _SQLCommand.Dispose()
    End If
    If Not _Conn Is Nothing Then
        _EConn.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
Try
 'do some stuff
 Catch ex As Exception
    errorArg = "Error details and description." 
    errorHandle(errorArg, ex)
  Sub errorHandle(ByVal errorArg As String, ByVal ex As System.Exception)
    Dim errorFile As String = "C:\Foldername\errorfile.txt"
    Dim errorWrite As New IO.StreamWriter(errorFile, True)
    Dim machname As String = System.Environment.MachineName.ToString
    Dim close As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(errorArg & vbCrLf & "Message", "System    Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    errorWrite.Write("*** ERROR on " & curDate & " @ " & machname & vbCrLf & errorArg & vbCrLf &   ex.ToString & vbCrLf)
    errorWrite.Close()
    If close = DialogResult.OK Then End
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

log4net does a nice job of logging errors to a text file, or syslog or the AdoNetAppender can log to a SQL Server database.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Try out **ELMAH** excellent for error logging.

**[ELMAH NuGet Package](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah)** is also available.

Also, Configure **Custom Error Pages** (in web.config) to avoid **Yellow pages of Error**.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (Error Logging Modules and Handlers)** is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or re-deployment.

Once ELMAH has been dropped into a running web application and configured appropriately, you get the following facilities without changing a single line of your code:

- Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions.
- A web page to remotely view the entire log of recoded exceptions.
- A web page to remotely view the full details of any one logged exception, including colored stack traces.
- In many cases, you can review the original yellow screen of death that ASP.NET generated for a given exception, even with customErrors mode turned off.
- An e-mail notification of each error at the time it occurs.
- An RSS feed of the last 15 errors from the log.